# Why can't I change values in the list this way?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to change the value of the elements in the list so that every single element is increased by 2 however this code does not work:

```
v = [-1, 1, 10]
for e in v:
    e = e + 2
```

but this one does:

```
v = [-1, 1, 10]
for i in range(len(v)):
    v[i] = v[i] + 2
```

can someone please explain why?

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, `e` takes on the value of each element in the list in a temporary variable. The values of each `v[i]` are copied to `e`, so `e = e + 2` is only changing that variable.

In the second example `v[i] = v[i] + 2` is directly changing the elements in the list without using another variable.